# What do YOU name a List object that holds every letter in a String

Tags: naming-conventions

I'm trying to get better at naming my variables and methods and this situation keeps coming up.

Take for example this code:

```
String word = "Hello";
List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
```

The List I created is simply going to contain every letter inside the word variable, but by simply appending "-List" to the word, this could lead to confusing code.

I would simply like to know what you'd name the List Object instead of "wordList". Or maybe you would use "wordList"?

A broader question would be something like:

What would you name an object that was formatted into an object of a different class but still held the same "information" as the original object?

Comment: I think that would depend on why you're putting the characters in the list in the first place. I also wouldn't call it "word" list. It doesn't contain words; it contains letters.

Comment: `letters` or `wordLetters` to be more explicit. I recommend taking a look at source code of open source projects to get ideas for naming conventions.